# Set Max Limit for an IP in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

I have an S3 bucket where users can upload some files.
In order to prevent users from uploading too many files, I want to control how many times a user can upload files to S3 per minute.

I want to set something like a single IP cannot upload more than 10 files in a minute.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, S3 does not have such a feature.

You'd have to build this yourself e.g. by vending short-lived, pre-signed URLs to your clients and throttling their requests for those URLs.